# Render a Zend Form SubForm but keep the naming as if the whole form where rendered

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a Zend Form with many nested subforms. When a user presses a button I call an ajax script and render one of the nested subforms and then put it in the correct location with javascript.

The problem is if you render a sub form on its own it treats it as a form in its own right and as such it ignore the parent forms in the naming of the elements.

For example my element is named

'questions[0][answers][3][text]'

but when I render an answers subform on its own it becomes

'3[text]'

I have googled and googled and the only thing which I found is this:
http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Rendering-a-sub-form-element-in-a-view-script-td643270.html

However I have had no luck with PrepareElements.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Zend sets naming prefixes when form is rendered, and can reuse it later. So there is a workaround:

```
  $form = new Zend_Form();
  $form->addSubForm(new Zend_Form_SubForm(), 'mysubform');
  // ... add elements and other subforms

  // workaround part
  $form->render();

  echo $form->mysubform;
```

The workaround part sets **belongsTo** in subforms and elements so that later when they are rendered separately they have name prefixes.